# Каким образом средствами t-sql получить только латиницу из строки?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Каким образом средствами t-sql получить только латиницу из строки, ну например

'Телефон Brand sku'

Получить 'Brand sku'

Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Для начала необходимо разбить строку на составляющие - слова.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnSplitString] 
( 
    @string NVARCHAR(MAX), 
    @delimiter CHAR(1) 
) 
RETURNS @output TABLE(splitdata NVARCHAR(MAX) 
) 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @start INT, @end INT 
    SELECT @start = 1, @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string) 
    WHILE @start < LEN(@string) + 1 BEGIN 
        IF @end = 0  
            SET @end = LEN(@string) + 1

        INSERT INTO @output (splitdata)  
        VALUES(SUBSTRING(@string, @start, @end - @start)) 
        SET @start = @end + 1 
        SET @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string, @start)

    END 
    RETURN 
END
```

Затем берём каждое слово и проверяем первую букву - если латиница, то выводим слово, иначе ничего.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ASCII(splitdata) BETWEEN 65 AND 90 THEN splitdata 
            WHEN ASCII(splitdata) BETWEEN 97 AND 122 THEN splitdata
            ELSE '' END 
       FROM [dbo].[fnSplitString] ('Телефон Brand sku',' ')
```

---

```
Brand    
sku
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Еще предложили вот такое решение

```
declare @str nvarchar(129) = N'Телефон Brand sku';

declare @lat nvarchar(24) = N' abcdefgh...';
declare @n table(n int primary key);

insert @n values(1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9); -- ...

select @str = case when CHARINDEX( SUBSTRING(@str, n, 1), @lat ) > 0    
                   then @str else STUFF(@str, n, 1, '') end    
       from @n where n <= LEN(@str) order by n desc;

select @str;
```